# How to use TPU to accelerate sentiment analysis using FinBert in Kaggle

Tags: python, bert-language-model, tpu

I am trying to analyze the sentiment of earnings calls using FinBert. Since I am analysing more than 40,000 earnings calls, the computation of the sentiment scores takes more than a week. Because of that, I want to use the TPU provided by Kaggle to accelerate this process.

But all the tutorials/ guides I could find where just dealing with the training of the model, but I just want to use one of the pre-trained versions and use the TPU to accelerate the sentiment analysis of the earnings calls.

```
from transformers import BertTokenizer, BertForSequenceClassification
from transformers import pipeline
```

```
try:
    tpu = tf.distribute.cluster_resolver.TPUClusterResolver() # TPU detection
except ValueError:
    tpu = None
    gpus = tf.config.experimental.list_logical_devices("GPU")
    
if tpu:
    tf.tpu.experimental.initialize_tpu_system(tpu)
    strategy = tf.distribute.experimental.TPUStrategy(tpu,) 
    print('Running on TPU ', tpu.cluster_spec().as_dict()['worker'])
elif len(gpus) > 1:
    strategy = tf.distribute.MirroredStrategy([gpu.name for gpu in gpus])
    print('Running on multiple GPUs ', [gpu.name for gpu in gpus])
elif len(gpus) == 1:
    strategy = tf.distribute.get_strategy() 
    print('Running on single GPU ', gpus[0].name)
else:
    strategy = tf.distribute.get_strategy() 
    print('Running on CPU')
print("Number of accelerators: ", strategy.num_replicas_in_sync)
```

````
finbert = BertForSequenceClassification.from_pretrained('yiyanghkust/finbert-tone',num_labels=3)
tokenizer = BertTokenizer.from_pretrained('yiyanghkust/finbert-tone')

nlp = pipeline("sentiment-analysis", model=finbert, tokenizer=tokenizer)```
````

#This is the loop I am using to calculate and score

```
for i in range(40001,len(clean_data)-1):
#for i in range(0,10):
    print(i)
    # Get QandA Text
    temp = test_data.iloc[i,3]
    sentences = nltk.sent_tokenize(temp)
    results = nlp(sentences)
    filename = clean_data.iloc[i,0]
    
#     positive = 0 
#     neutral = 0 
#     negative = 0 
    j = 0
    positive = 0
    neutral = 0 
    negative = 0 
    for j in range (0,len(results)):
        label = results[j]["label"]
        if label == "Positive":
            positive = positive + 1
        elif label == "Neutral": 
            neutral = neutral + 1 
        else:
            negative = negative + 1  
​
            
    per_pos_qanda = positive / len(results)
    per_neg_qanda = negative / len(results)
    net_score_qanda = per_pos_qanda - per_neg_qanda
    
    finbert_results.iloc[i,0] = filename
    finbert_results.iloc[i,7] = per_pos_qanda
    finbert_results.iloc[i,8] = per_neg_qanda
    finbert_results.iloc[i,9] = net_score_qanda
```

Do I now need to incorporate the TPU in the for loop code when I am calling the algorithm? So, in this line?

```
results = nlp(sentences)
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you're referring to inference and not training. In that case also you can benefit from TPUs, for example by using distributed strategy. Please refer to this guide https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/distribute/Strategy